# argument "fit" missing : R mob() in party package

Tags: r, party

```
#Logistic Model Based Recursive Partitioning
library(party)
data("PimaIndiansDiabetes2",package = "mlbench")
set.seed(16)
n=nrow(PimaIndiansDiabetes2)
train <- sample(1:n, 600, FALSE)
#mass and pedigree are conditioning varibles for logistic regression
f<-"diabetes ~ mass + pedigree|glucose + pregnant + pressure + triceps +
insulin + age"
fit <- mob(f, data=PimaIndiansDiabetes2[train, ], model=glinearModel, family=binomial())
plot(fit)
```

Error in formals(fit) : argument "fit" is missing, with no default
what exactly is meant by argument missing, kindly clarify

Comment: I edited the reply by @EricFail slightly to point out more precisely that the model formula needs to be a `formula` not a `character`. Additionally, you might consider using the `glmtree()` function in the `partykit` package which has a somewhat more convenient interface and offers many additional options.

Answer (score 2):

The model formula has to be a `"formula"` and not a `"character"`. So `f` needs to be defined without the quotes:

```
f <- diabetes ~ mass + pedigree | glucose + pregnant + pressure + triceps + insulin + age
```

Or you can move it directly into the `mob()` call. Then you get this plot,

```
# mass and pedigree are conditioning variables for logistic regression
fit <- mob(diabetes ~ mass + pedigree | glucose + pregnant + pressure + triceps + insulin + age, 
  data = PimaIndiansDiabetes2[train, ], model = glinearModel, family = binomial())
plot(fit)
```

[image: Model-based Recursive Partitioning]

Comment: You can also create a formula object from a string using `f <- as.formula("diabetes ~ mass + pedigree | glucose + pregnant + pressure + triceps + insulin + age")`. See [link](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Formulas/Creating_a_formula_from_a_string/).

Comment: @MarcoSandri, good point. Always many ways to do things in R.